# How to feed bokeh streaming interface by a c++ application

Tags: c++, zeromq, bokeh

I want to use bokeh to display a time series and provide the data with updates via `source.stream(someDict)`. The data is, however, generated by a c++ application (server) that may run on the same machine or a machine in the network. I was looking into transmitting the updated data (only the newly added lines of the time series) via [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/) to the python program (client).

The transmission of the message seems easy enough to implement but

1. the dictionary is column based. Is it not more efficient to append lines, i.e. one line per point in time, and send this?
2. If there is no good way for the first, what kind of object should I send? Do I need to marshal the information or is it sufficient to make a long string like `{col1:[a,b,c,...], col2:[...],...}` and send this to the client? I expect to send not more than a few hundred lines with 10 floats per second.

Thanks for all helpful answers.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is too general to offer any specific advice. It's unclear for instance if you are running a native bokeh server app, or using `bokeh.client` and `push_session`. This question might be better suited for the Bokeh public mailing list, where a more iterative discussion is normal (mods here do not approve of iterative collaboration, calling them "not an answer")

Comment: Ok thanks, the follow-up discussion can be found here:
[bokeh mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/NBUrwou38QQ)

Comment: If you have the bandwidth to self-answer with a summary and/or some example code I'll def upvote